# ASP.NET 5 Error: the verb must be specified by using the -verb argument. Error count=1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net5

I am pretty new to the .net and I had this error while trying to publish my website to file system.

Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb.   This error is shown when I try to publish in the default detination

```
Copying to output path  C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\GpsTracking103
Multiple commands defined. Defaulting to web.
Using command 'web' as the entry point for web.config.
Time elapsed 00:02:45.9471627
Publishing with publish method [FileSystem]
Publishing files to C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GpsTracking\artifacts\bin\GpsTracking\Release\PublishOutput
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\GpsTracking103\' -dest:contentPath='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GpsTracking\artifacts\bin\GpsTracking\Release\PublishOutput' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): Error : Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): Error : Error count: 1.
```

I have searched for hours for an answer but nothing solved my problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because there is an ' in your path name (or your username actually):

```
["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:contentPath='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\GpsTracking103\' -dest:contentPath='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GpsTracking\artifacts\bin\GpsTracking\Release\PublishOutput' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule]
```

Try deploying to a different folder like `c:\projects\` ad also the source path could be the issue.

Comment: I have tried also on azure but still same error, ["C:\Pr.... -source:IisApp='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\GpsTracking103\wwwroot' -dest:IisApp='gpstracking2016',ComputerName='https://gpstracking2016.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd',UserName='$gpstracking2016',Password='{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enableLink:contentLibExtension  -retryAttempts:2]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): Error : Error: The verb must be specified by using the -verb argument.

Comment: `IisApp='C:\Users\Iulica'sPc\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\GpsTracking10‌​3\wwwroot'` 
This will never work because it'll read it like:
`IisApp='C:\Users\Iulica'` 
the trailing stuff is caussing the error. You have to change your path.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Important things to remember here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569005(v=ws.10).aspx

In order for the sync operation to function correctly, the Msdeploy.exe.configsettings file must be the same on the source and destination computers. If you add any rules or custom providers to the Msdeploy.exe.configsettings file, make sure that this configuration file is identical on the source and the destination computers before you perform a synchronization.