# Error deploying to Azure App Service when no changes were made to pipeline or release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Getting the follow error deploying to Azure App Service.

```
2023-11-06T22:17:18.7364356Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\c\r2\b\test1 & test2 artifacts\drop\test2_888.zip' -dest:contentPath='azureWebDev',ComputerName='https://mycomputername.net',UserName='$myUsername',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -userAgent:VSTS_sd1324dc-7762-4e41-8aa2-b2abcde_Release__1234_5678_9
2023-11-06T22:17:18.7364356Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\c\r2\b\test1 & test2 artifacts\drop\test2_888.zip' -dest:contentPath='azureWebDev',ComputerName='https://mycomputername.net',UserName='$myUsername',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -userAgent:VSTS_sd1324dc-7762-4e41-8aa2-b2abcde_Release__1234_5678_9
2023-11-06T22:17:18.7364356Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\c\r2\b\test1 & test2 artifacts\drop\test2_888.zip' -dest:contentPath='azureWebDev',ComputerName='https://mycomputername.net',UserName='$myUsername',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -userAgent:VSTS_sd1324dc-7762-4e41-8aa2-b2abcde_Release__1234_5678_9
2023-11-06T22:17:18.9042826Z ##[error]Error: Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb.
Error count: 1.
'test2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As far as I can tell, no changes were made to the release pipeline or the pipeline itself. I have tried removing all spaces in source alias ("test1 & test2 artifacts" to "test1&test2artifacts") as per a related error in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745519/asp-net-5-error-the-verb-must-be-specified-by-using-the-verb-argument-error-c) but the -dest argument error still comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am experiencing the same issue, try removing the `&` from your source alias.

Answer (score 1):

If you use command lines to run the deployment, you can try to use the double quotation (**`" "`**) to surround the patten of package path.

For example:

```bash
"$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\test1 & test2 artifacts\drop\test2_888.zip"
```

Similar, if you use the [**Azure App Service deploy task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-rm-web-app-deployment-v4?view=azure-pipelines), in the filed '**Package or folder**', you also can try to set its value like as above.

[image]